# How to move the first 2 rows of a file to the end with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, row

I have a file with 2 columns and 10 rows:

```
01/12/2019  234.75
02/12/2019  303.6666666666667
03/12/2019  213.29166666666663
04/12/2019  187.91666666666663
05/12/2019  191.875
06/12/2019  188.25
07/12/2019  208.5833333333333
08/12/2019  184.125
09/12/2019  210.16666666666663
10/12/2019  315.4166666666667
```

I want to move the first 2 rows at the end of the file. How I could do that with pandas ? The file is a sample, in fact there may be many more rows.

```
col_names=['day','val']
df_moved = pd.read_csv(o,sep='\t',header=None,names=col_names,skiprows=[1]) #for skipping the first two rows
```

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with selecting rows by positions:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.iloc[2:], df.iloc[:2]])
```

Or [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with appended index values:

```
df1 = df.reindex(df.index[2:].append(df.index[:2]))
```

Or solution with [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[np.r_[2:len(df), 0:2]]
```

---

```
print (df1)
          day         val
2  03/12/2019  213.291667
3  04/12/2019  187.916667
4  05/12/2019  191.875000
5  06/12/2019  188.250000
6  07/12/2019  208.583333
7  08/12/2019  184.125000
8  09/12/2019  210.166667
9  10/12/2019  315.416667
0  01/12/2019  234.750000
1  02/12/2019  303.666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `iloc` and `np.arange`:

```
>>> df.iloc[[*np.arange(2, len(df)), *np.arange(2)]]
   a   b
2  3   6
3  4   7
4  5   8
5  6   9
6  7  10
0  1   4
1  2   5
>>>
```